# Not all my code paths return a value.

Tags: c#, if-statement, do-while

I deliberately designed this code, and i can't use it. Can i override this fail-safe?

```
do // Checks if the chosen name is also the right name
        {
            string test;
            Console.Write("Are you sure " + temp + " is the right name? (y/n)\n");
            test = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("\n");
            if (test.ToLower() == "y")
            {
                nameIsRight = true;
                return temp;
            }
            else if (test.ToLower() == "n")
            {
                Console.Write("What is your name then?\n");
                temp = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        } while (nameIsRight == false);
```

Comment: Even if the code path is never possible, you should return something from non void functions for the compilers sanity. Just return a null or some sort of default value ie. an empty string.

Comment: Yeah. return null - finished.

Comment: Personally i'd use a void function and an event handler/callback but thats just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `return` statement *after* this loop:

```
do // Checks if the chosen name is also the right name
{
   //...
}while (!nameIsRight);

return something;
```

UPDATE: As @hvd stated, you always return from loop. So, possibly throwing exception is a better way here.

UPDATE2: I think best solution is to get rid of boolean flag and inner return statement:

```
do // Checks if the chosen name is also the right name
{
    Console.Write("Are you sure " + temp + " is the right name? (y/n)\n");
    key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
    Console.Write("\n");

    if (key == ConsoleKey.N)
    {
        Console.Write("What is your name then?\n");
        temp = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    Console.Write("\n");
} while (key != ConsoleKey.Y);

return temp;
```

Comment: Er... that `return something;` would never be executed. There is no way to exit the loop without already returning, because the only place where `nameIsRight` gets set to `true` in the code in the question is immediately followed by another `return` statement. If the loop is supposed to be one that doesn't terminate (doesn't terminate normally), a more common approach would be to write it as a `while (true)` loop. That avoids the need for statements that have no effect.

Comment: Yes, but the compiler doesn't know that for sure (Search "Halting Problem").

Comment: @hvd well, return statement will make compiler happy, but if its not possible to exist loop without return, then I'd go with throwing exception

Comment: I also thought of raising an exception, not sure of that value added tho, sanity check?

Comment: My problem is that this loop technically should be able to run forever. If i throw an exeption, wouldn't it return the wrong string? I haven't really had any experience working with exeptions yet.

Comment: Throw the exception outside the loop. Incase for some reason you exit the loop without returning value..... (Search "Programmer Paranoia")

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I still don't see the benefit of that over a `while (true)` loop. That does not have to be followed by any statement.

Comment: @hvd the compiler expects all code paths in a non void function to return a value of the assigned return type. All code paths in a `public string whatever()` need to return a string or null. Its not smart enough to optimize code after the infinite loop out at compile time, so it thinks code past the loop can be executed and it sees there is no return value given at that code path.

Comment: @j_mcnally Try `static int Main() { while (true) { return 0; } }`. I was able to compile it without problems. In this case, the condition is known at compile time, and the compiler accepts this.

Comment: i believe it can optimize, the while (true) as a static value. When you add a variable to the while clause, it does not optimize the return path.

Comment: @j_mcnally Exactly. And I did suggest to use a `while (true)` loop.

Comment: @hvd I edited answer 6 minutes ago. I think OP code needs to be refactored

Comment: ahh i think i got lost in the conversation. yes that is correct tho.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yes, that does look like a good approach to me too. :)

Comment: @Herbstein If an exception is thrown, the method doesn't return any value. Execution is continued at nearest catch block, if present. Otherwise your program will crash.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do something like this:

EDIT: Corrected code.

```
do // Checks if the chosen name is also the right name
{
    string test;
    Console.Write("Are you sure " + temp + " is the right name? (y/n)\n");
    test = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("\n");
    if (test.ToLower() == "y")
    {
        nameIsRight = true;

    }
    else if (test.ToLower() == "n")
    {
        Console.Write("What is your name then?\n");
        temp = Console.ReadLine();
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input!!!");
        continue;
    }                
} while (nameIsRight == false);

return temp;
```

You should not be returning your variable from inside the loop, but only setting the condition to true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Just learn to write better readable (and maintainable) code.

```
// Ask what you have to ask before the loop
Console.Write("Enter the name: \n");
string result = Console.ReadLine();

while(true) 
{
    Console.Write("Are you sure " + result + " is the right name? (y/n)\n");
    string test = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("\n");
    if (test.ToLower() == "y")
    {
        // it will exit the loop
        break;
    }
    // when loop is not exited, keep asking until user answers with "y"
    Console.Write("What is your name then?\n");
    result = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("\n");
};

// result will always contain the latest input, as it's not possible for the user to leave
// except closing the application
return result;
```

This way you will never get in such a situation and the code is more readable, because you clearly see the break when the loop leaves and you don't need any returns inside the loop at all and you don't need to manage a loop condition (`while (nameIsRight == false)`).